# How to use jmeter using ant task - load testing on Dot Net application

Tags: jmeter

I have just tried jmeter examples using ant task. I got the HTML output. Now,

I built my application using c#.net,asp.net,javascript,jQuery,Ajax,Json etc.
This is the url `http://localhost/test/pagemanager.aspx` which shows my
LOGIN Screen. Once after login, the user can access over multiple menus(pages) to access like checking their personal data, overall student details like batch wise, registering a new student etc... My URL `http://localhost/test/pagemanager.aspx`remains constant at every time.

The site can be accessed by multiple users for multiple times. I needs to find a load testing. Can some one give me a configuration step to find load testng to my application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if also am using content-type, where should include ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend recording your test scenario steps starting from login via JMeter build-in [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder).

See [JMeter Proxy Step by Step guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) for detailed instructions.

Once you have recorded test flow you'll need to do some correlation as the nature of ASP.NET applications assumes mandatory dynamic parameters like VIEWSTATE. So you'll need to extract VIEWSTATE and similar from previous server response and add it to next request.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) for more details.